# Resizable Git Bash for Windows

Tags: windows, git, terminal-emulator

Is there a Git Bash<sup>[1](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)</sup> replacement for Windows whose window can be resized by dragging the top or right border?

**Edit:** Adding the [requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software):

- Is free.
- Resizable - Git Bash uses cmd.exe as the console host, and the only way cmd.exe can be resized is from Properties.
- Not being too big - like recommending to install Cygwin or an Ubuntu VM. A replacement of cmd.exe should be a couple of megabytes big.
- Preserves the coloring of Git Bash, where added lines are colored green in `git diff` for example.

Comment: I use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) at work and I'm pretty sure it's resizable... I actually can't remember how I got it set up with Git but if you don't have an answer by tomorrow when I'm back at work I can try to figure it out for you!

Comment: @TimMalone I found a way to use cmder from a SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107769/how-do-a-i-run-msysgit-in-cmder. It works but for some reason is very slow when I run git `sh --login -i` inside it - when you enter a command and press enter there is a visible half a second interval before it gets processed. So if MinGW doesn't have that issue I'd give it a try. Btw are you talking about the old msys, because the new one uses cmd.exe and is not resizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend cmder. It should be everything you need. It offers a 4.27MB version called "Mini" and basically replaces cmd.exe. cmder is basically a nicer looking UI (that you can easily change the window dimensions) of Conemu and includes enhancements from Clink. It's completely portable in its own directory. It also preserves the coloring of Git Bash and also allows for UNIX commands aswell.

## [cmder](http://cmder.net/) ([open source](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder))

> Cmder is a software package created out of pure frustration over the absence of nice console emulators on Windows. It is based on amazing software, and spiced up with the Monokai color scheme and a custom prompt layout.
>
> [image: screenshot main]
>
> [image: screenshot git diff]